# Matlab Calling Java 8 `java.time` Class

Tags: java, matlab, class, time

Following [these](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=264) examples in:

- Matlab R2018a, Windows 8 64bit,
- `MATLAB_JAVA` environment variable: Both if not used, or if set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251` just downloaded minutes ago,
- `version -java`: `Java 1.8.0_251-b08 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode`,
- `computer('arch')`: `win64`

I tried to run this Java 8 `java.time` class call, and I find an error:

```
>> localdate=java.time.LocalDate.parse('2020-04-19')
No method 'parse' with matching signature found for class 'java.time.LocalDate'.
```

Simple calls such as this, works:

```
>> java.time.LocalDate.now
2020-04-19 [1x1 LocalDate]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `java.time.LocalDate.parse` [method's signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) is defined to take a `CharSequence`, not a `String`.

```
public static LocalDate parse(CharSequence text)
```

Matlab will auto-convert Matlab `char` and `string` arrays to `java.lang.String`, but not to `CharSequence`. So you have to supply an explicit conversion by calling `java.lang.String(...)` on the string yourself:

```
>> localdate=java.time.LocalDate.parse('2020-04-19')
No method 'parse' with matching signature found for class 'java.time.LocalDate'. 
>> localdate=java.time.LocalDate.parse(java.lang.String('2020-04-19'))
localdate =
2020-04-19
>>
```

Comment: A very subtle problem! Thanks.